# I need to Show/hide Text based on if there is an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thank you in advance.  I need text to show up when there is content in the src attribute of an img tag.  I need some JS that will detect if an attribute has content, then if it does a p tag is visible.

**html**

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="SampleJS.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p id="sponsorText">Now you see me!<img src="" class="sponsorImg" id="sponsorText" /></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**js**

```
var attr = $().attr('src');

if (typeof attr !== "" && attr !== false){
    alert('no image.');
    }
```

but at this point I can not even get the JS to detect and give an alert.

I need the Jscript to detect if there is a filename.jpeg and then if there is it triggers the text.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use jQuery... Did you forget to include the jQuery library?

Comment: `$().attr('src');`? Add  a jQuery selector and you're good to go. I'm refraining from posting an answer as you should have a minimal understanding of the problem, which you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Include the jQuery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Secondly, Create the script as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // code here..
});
```

Thirdly, you need to provide a selector to work on.

```
var attr = $('img').attr('src'); // add img element
```

This would work now.